# Replace null by another value in 2D String array using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I want to replace `null` value by string `Z` in two dimensional array.
I have data like this:

```
String[][] userData = { { "User A", "A" }, { null, null }, { "User B", "B" } };
```

Now I need to change this `userData` like below:

```
String[][] userData = { { "User A", "A" }, { "Z", "Z" }, { "User B", "B" } };
```

How do I achieve this by java 8 stream and get back the result in same format (2D string array) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a lambda expression to regenerate the entire array you could use a pair of `IntStream.range(int, int)` calls to generate the valid array indices and then use a single `forEach` to replace any `null`(s). Like,

```
String[][] userData = { { "User A", "A" }, { null, null }, { "User B", "B" } };
IntStream.range(0, userData.length).forEach(x -> 
            IntStream.range(0, userData[x].length).forEach(y -> {
    if (userData[x][y] == null) {
        userData[x][y] = "Z";
    }
}));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(userData));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[[User A, A], [Z, Z], [User B, B]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check If this works for you

```
        String[][] userData = {{"User A", "A" }, {null, null}, {"User B", "B" }};
        userData = Arrays.stream(userData).map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)
            .map(a -> a!=null ? a : "Z").toArray(String[]::new)).toArray(String[][]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(userData));
        //[[User A, A], [Z, Z], [User B, B]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a solution without using stream, but requires **java 8+**.

( [List.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) was introduced in java 8 which accepts a `UnaryOperator` which would be applied to each element of the list)

```java
String[] replace = {null, null};
String[] replaceWith = { "Z", "Z" };

List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(userData);
list.replaceAll(arr -> Arrays.equals(arr, replace) ? replaceWith : arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.toArray()));
```

Output:

```
[[User A, A], [Z, Z], [User B, B]]
```